# Do I have to call SignInClient.signOut() function if I use firebase authentication?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Do I have to use `SignInClient.signOut()` function AND `FirebaseAuth.signOut()` at the same time to log out?

If yes, why https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin does not have information about it? Why a `FirebaseAuth.signOut()` is not enough?

I've started wondering about it while reading: https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseAuthentication/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firebaseauthapp/main/MainActivity.java#L74

And if Google requires it, does Facebook authentication also do?

Comment: Aside from my answer, if you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're signed in to Firebase with Google provider and you want to sign out from both Google and Firebase, then yes, you have to call `signOut()` once on a `FirebaseAuth` object and once on a `GoogleSignInClient` object like this:

```
firebaseAuth.signOut();
googleSignInClient.signOut();
```

> Why a FirebaseAuth.signOut() is not enough?

It's because it signs out the user only from Firebase. The Firebase sign-out operation isn't related in any with the sign-out operation from Google.

> Does Facebook authentication also do?

Yes, you should proceed in the exact same way.